# How to convert a file into a dictionary?

Tags: python, file, dictionary

I have a file comprising two columns, i.e.,

```
1 a 
2 b 
3 c
```

I wish to read this file to a dictionary such that column 1 is the key and column 2 is the value, i.e.,

```
d = {1:'a', 2:'b', 3:'c'}
```

The file is small, so efficiency is not an issue.

Answer (score 181, accepted):

```
d = {}
with open("file.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
       (key, val) = line.split()
       d[int(key)] = val
```

Comment: Could you explain the with statement ?

Comment: `with` is used here to handle the file clean up. When you leave the block (either just by normal execution flow or by an exception) there file will be automatically closed. You can read more about context-managers in Python here: http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm

Comment: `for line in open("file.txt"):` do cleanup the same way. And if f is a local value the `f` is released when the scope is lost. The only case where this statement is useful is for long function  (not good for quality), or if you use a global variable.

Comment: @VGE, `for line in open('file.txt')` does *not* do cleanup the same way.  Not all Python implementations are the same.  `with` guarantees the file will be closed when the block is exited.  When the `for` line is complete, `close` *may* be called.  `CPython` it will, but versions like `IronPython` have lazy garbage collectors.

Comment: Is int really necessary here?  Perhaps he wanted the numbers to be strings?

Comment: For those with a Java background, the `with` keyword is similar to Java 7's [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)

Comment: reading empty lines will throw a `ValueError: need more than 0 values to unpack` - ignore empty lines & comments after the `for` with: `if not line.startswith('#') and line.strip():`

Comment: is there a faster way to set the dictionary such as JSON.stringify the file instead of reading each line? if it is a large file

Comment: key, val = line.split()[0],line.split()[1]

Comment: @VladH This was a **Brilliant** solution! Thanks! Still works over here, in Corona 2021.  //Wishes!

Answer (score 20):

This will leave the key as a string:

```
with open('infile.txt') as f:
  d = dict(x.rstrip().split(None, 1) for x in f)
```

Comment: A simple `dict([line.split() for line in f])` is sufficient, imo.

Comment: @sukhbir: if you read question, you'll see that's not what op wants.

Comment: @SilentGhost: I read that the OP wants keys as integers, but Ignacio's solution (as well as the one I deleted), has keys as a string (as pointed out by Ignacio himself).

Comment: I was confused why we don't need [] when passing in the dict argument. ie `dict([x.rstrip().split(None, 1) for x in f])` instead of `dict(x.rstrip().split(None, 1) for x in f)`. For those thinking the same thing, the former is a generator expression instead of list comprehension as explained here: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289(PEP-289). Learnt something new!

Comment: @peaxol: We use a generator expression instead of a list comprehension in order to not create an intermediate list.

Answer (score 11):

You can also use a [dict comprehension](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/) like:

```
with open("infile.txt") as f:
    d = {int(k): v for line in f for (k, v) in [line.strip().split(None, 1)]}
```

Comment: Yeah, you can absolutely use comprehension here. But I find myself less and less doing it, as it breaks a few of the Zen of Python rules ("Explicit is better than implicit" and "Readabilty counts")

Answer (score 5):

```
def get_pair(line):
    key, sep, value = line.strip().partition(" ")
    return int(key), value

with open("file.txt") as fd:    
    d = dict(get_pair(line) for line in fd)
```

Comment: why not `partition`? and `with` statement?

Comment: @SilentGhost: I didn't know about partition! but why is it better to str.split in this case? regarding "with": maybe you can clarify this for me: isn't it enough to go out of scope for the file descriptor to be closed? I guess in a exception the file main remain open, I'll change it.

Comment: `partition` is faster and is created for exactly this purpose.

Comment: whether descriptor is closed or not is a detail of implementation. `with` is a simple way to ensure that it is.

Comment: it would still require `strip`, i'd say.

Answer (score 3):

**By dictionary comprehension**

```
d = { line.split()[0] : line.split()[1] for line in open("file.txt") }
```

**Or By pandas**

```
import pandas as pd 
d = pd.read_csv("file.txt", delimiter=" ", header = None).to_dict()[0]
```

Comment: By pandas only takes the first column

Comment: @Samer Ayoub
The above solution(dictionary comprehension) works if both keys and value are one word long. If my text file has following data.How do I make year as keys and winning team as values.

1903 Boston Americans
1904 No World Series
1905 New York Giants
1906 Chicago White Sox
1907 Chicago Cubs
1908 Chicago Cubs

Comment: @Ridhi Sorry for belated reply. You can either split on the first space only  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30636248/split-a-string-only-by-first-space-in-python   Or  Use a regular expression as argument for split()

Comment: @SamerAyoub- Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

## Simple Option

Most methods for storing a dictionary use JSON, Pickle, or line reading.  Providing you're not editing the dictionary outside of Python, this simple method should suffice for even complex dictionaries.  Although Pickle will be better for larger dictionaries.

```
x = {1:'a', 2:'b', 3:'c'}
f = 'file.txt'
print(x, file=open(f,'w'))    # file.txt >>> {1:'a', 2:'b', 3:'c'}
y = eval(open(f,'r').read())
print(x==y)                   # >>> True
```

Answer (score 0):

IMHO a bit more pythonic to use generators (probably you need 2.7+ for this):

```
with open('infile.txt') as fd:
    pairs = (line.split(None) for line in fd)
    res   = {int(pair[0]):pair[1] for pair in pairs if len(pair) == 2 and pair[0].isdigit()}
```

This will also filter out lines not starting with an integer or not containing exactly two items

Answer (score 0):

If you love one liners, try:

```
d=eval('{'+re.sub('\'[\s]*?\'','\':\'',re.sub(r'([^'+input('SEP: ')+',]+)','\''+r'\1'+'\'',open(input('FILE: ')).read().rstrip('\n').replace('\n',',')))+'}')
```

*Input FILE = Path to file, SEP = Key-Value separator character*

Not the most elegant or efficient way of doing it, but quite interesting nonetheless :)

Answer (score 0):

I had a requirement to take values from text file and use as key value pair. i have content in text file as key = value, so i have used split method with separator as "=" and
wrote below code

```
d = {}
file = open("filename.txt")
for x in file:
    f = x.split("=")
    d.update({f[0].strip(): f[1].strip()})
```

By using strip method any spaces before or after the "=" separator are removed and you will have the expected data in dictionary format

Comment: Hi there, welcome to Stack Overflow!  Your approach is distinct from other users, but could you edit it to replace the `=` with a ` ` to answer the question?

Answer (score -1):

```
import re

my_file = open('file.txt','r')
d = {}
for i in my_file:
  g = re.search(r'(\d+)\s+(.*)', i) # glob line containing an int and a string
  d[int(g.group(1))] = g.group(2)
```

Comment: I don't think this is the best approach.

Comment: @Seafoid said "The file is small, so efficiency is not an issue." `split()` does not work almost silently if the file format is not sane.

Answer (score -1):

Here's another option...

```
events = {}
for line in csv.reader(open(os.path.join(path, 'events.txt'), "rb")):
    if line[0][0] == "#":
        continue
    events[line[0]] = line[1] if len(line) == 2 else line[1:]
```