# PYTHON: Read a file into a dictionary with column n as key and column m as value

Tags: python, dictionary

I know how to do it if its just two columns, but what if the file is like:

```
01 asd 023 green
01 dff 343 blue
02 fdf 342 yellow
02 fff 232 brown
02 kjf 092 green
03 kja 878 blue
```

and say, I would like column 2 to be the key to my dictionary and column 4 to my content for that key? I was thinking, a way to go around this problem would be to totally delete the other useless columns so that only the two I need remain, then I can use a script which I also saw on this website to make the dictionary

[Python - file to dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4803999/python-file-to-dictionary)

Of course, this is a way around the problem, any tip is greatly appreciated.

Comment: How do you know your keys are in column 2 and the values in column 4? How are the columns delimited? Always by spaces like in your example?

Comment: yes, sorry about that. They are separated by spaces, and this is an example, lets say for this example, my keys are always on 2 and values always on 4

Comment: Ok, then I would go with @NPE's solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
d = {}
with open('data.txt') as f:
  for line in f:
    tok = line.split()
    d[tok[1]] = tok[3]
print(d)
```

This produces

```
{'kja': 'blue', 'kjf': 'green', 'fdf': 'yellow', 'asd': 'green', 'fff': 'brown', 'dff': 'blue'}
```

[`split()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) (without an argument) splits the lines into lists of strings. `tok[1]` and `tok[3]` then use [list indexing](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#lists) to address the second and fourth values in those lists, assigning them to a [dictionary](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)'s keys and values (`d[key] = value`).

Comment: thank you for the help, what you did was read the file in (lines) and split the columns up. The d[tok[1]] = tok[3] part means you use the tok[1] as column 1, and tok[3] as column 4 right? Thanks alot for the simple to understand code, I hope my beginner's vocabulary didn't annoy anyone. Thanks for the rapid response as well!

Comment: @Dergyll: You're welcome. Yes, `tok[1]` (column 2) is the key and `tok[3]` (column 4) is the value.

Comment: @NPE Just to note that in `line.strip().split()` the `strip()` is redundant because of the behaviour of `split()` / `split(None)`

Comment: Hello NPE, I get a funky error: "AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'" what does that mean? Is my original file in a weird format or something? Its a txt file...

Comment: @Dergyll: This exact code works for me. Without seeing the exact code that you're running and the exception stack trace, it's hard to say what's going wrong in your case.

Answer (score 2):

Something like

```
from operator import itemgetter
keyval = itemgetter(1, 3)
with open('file') as fin:
    keyvals = (keyval(line.split()) for line in fin)
    my_dict = dict(keyvals)
```

**Notes:**

This differs from @NPE's answer in the sense it uses the builtin `dict` for initialisation, rather than declaring it outside the loop. It also utilises `itemgetter` as a key retrieval function which takes the 2nd and 4th values from each line (when split by spaces) and uses a generator expression to apply that to each line in the file.

There's also a slight advantage (although, usually not that important) that should `my_dict = dict(keyvals)` fail, then the name never ends up being bound, while if something occurs by assigning key by key, then it's possible a `dict` declared outside the `with` statement ends up "dirty".

Comment: using itemgetter is unnecessary

Comment: @JonMartin and splitting `line` twice as per your example is?

Comment: I only did that for a quick two-line solution. It's certainly better to split it once.

Answer (score 0):

```
d = {}
with open("file.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        (key1, val1, key2, val2) = line.split()
        d[int(key1)] = val
        d[int(key2)] = val2
```

Will get you all of them. Otherwise, you can do something along the lines on NPE.

Answer (score 0):

```
for line in f.readlines():
    my_dic[line.split(' ')[1]] = line.split(' ')[3]
```

Comment: `for line in f.readlines()` is just `for line in f` ... (unless you intend to read the entire file into memory)