# File to dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Python - file to dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4803999/python-file-to-dictionary)

I've been looking on this website, and racking my brain, but I just can't find the answer.
I have a file of words that are matched with numbers, delimited with '*'.
Now I have to find a way to convert this file to a dictionary in python and look up words from another text and assign the values from the dictionary file.

I know how to import a plain-text file, just not how I can make it "act like a dictionary"
does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks everyone

Comment: Could you provide some example data of your file?

Comment: And an example of the code you've tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your file is one per line, e.g.

```
chicken*5
dog*3
...
```

You can do

```
with open("path/to/file") as f:
    data = [line.split("*") for line in f]
data = dict((word, int(cnt)) for (word, cnt) in data)
```

Comment: Or you could do `data = {word: int(cnt) for line in f for word, cnt in line.split(*)}` so you don't need the intermediary list.

Comment: @Volatility, Yep, sure can. I tend to avoid multiple `for`s in the same list comprehension, but in this case I agree your solution is pretty readable. `dict` comprehensions are also quite cool (for Python >= 2.7)

Comment: Hey @Tom, thanks for the help, however if I try your code I get the error: ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack. Do you know what that's about?

Comment: Do you have lines in your file that do not fit the <word>*<num> format? Perhaps empty lines? You can ignore empty lines easily by doing `[line.split("*") for line in f if line.strip()]` in the second line.

Comment: I get the same error:
    data = dict((word, int(cnt)) for (word, cnt) in data)
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack

Comment: The data is like this blabla*3 blablabla*3 5

Comment: Are they separated by newlines? And what's the '5' in the end of your example?

Comment: there are sometimes several values next to words, and yes, a new line is started every time

Comment: Several values next to words...how would you want to represent those? And are there *any* lines in your file that don't match that format, e.g. do not contain a *?

Comment: Just checked the file, for some reason a whole bunch have no asterixes....

Comment: @Volatility has two syntax errors in the dict comprehension, which is confusing matters more.  It should be like `{word: int(cnt) for line in f for word, cnt in (line.split('*'),)}`