# Split a string only by first space in python

Tags: python, string, split

I have string for example: `"238 NEO Sports"`. I want to split this string only at the **first** space. The output should be `["238","NEO Sports"]`.

One way I could think of is by using `split()` and finally merging the last two strings returned. Is there a better way?

Comment: `re.sub(r'^[^\s]+', r'\1', s)`

Answer (score 183, accepted):

Just pass the count as second parameter to `str.split` function.

```
>>> s = "238 NEO Sports"
>>> s.split(" ", 1)
['238', 'NEO Sports']
```

Answer (score 38):

RTFM: [`str.split(sep=None, maxsplit=-1)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)

```
>>> "238 NEO Sports".split(None, 1)
['238', 'NEO Sports']
```

Comment: This is the only answer which works with any whitespace such as tabs. +1

Comment: I think it is really a bad style to supply an argument set to its default value just to move to the next argument which is directly accessible as a keyword argument. Much better answer by Shubham Gupta: `"238 NEO Sports".split(maxsplit=1)`

Comment: @pabouk Normally I'd agree, but the downside of that is it only works on Python 3.3+. If you want to write a cross-compatible code which works on Python 2 + Python 3 the same way, you have to do it like this. Do note the answer is from 7 years ago..

Answer (score 5):

**Use in-built terminology, as it will helpful to remember for future reference. When in doubt always prefer string.split(`shift+tab`)

```
string.split(maxsplit = 1)
```

Answer (score 3):

Use string.split()

```
string = "238 NEO Sports"
print string.split(' ', 1)
```

Output:

```
['238', 'NEO Sports']
```