# How to get arguments for on_message event in discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm currently new to coding, And I'm planning to make a utility bot. So basically, what I am trying to do here is getting the second argument for my on_message event. But how can I do that?
I'm making an auto math module for my bot, without using the prefix. For example: `solve 5*5` and the bot was supposed to automatically answer it by reading the second argument.

### My Code:

---

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('solve'):
        expression = # Where it supposed to read the arguments
        await math(message, expression) # math function
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Split a string only by first space in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30636248/split-a-string-only-by-first-space-in-python)

Comment: You might want to look into `discord.ext.commands` for nicer command handling like this. Also please please please please do *not* use `eval`/`exec`/anything of that sort when evaluating math (what if I did `solve await ctx.send(client.http.token)`?)... to be on the safe side use `ast.literal_eval`

Comment: @EricJin Yes. I used `eval(expression)` for my math command. But I also used `try/except` which forbids some codes running. I tried it out myself, But thanks for that recommendation. I would use that

Comment: You can *never* forbid anyone from doing anything once you already are executing the code directly. There are ways to access things even if the namespace is destroyed. For one, `''.__class__.__bases__[0]` gives you `object` even if you try to disallow that.

Comment: @EricJin I tried doing `ast.literal_eval` but i ran into some problem: `malformed node or string on line 1: <ast.BinOp object at 0x760ceb4310>`. I would ask this as question.

Comment: Yeah, I don't think bitwise operations are allowed under that. You do have to pay something in exchange for the increased security.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `message.content.startswith()` means you already know that `message.content` is a string. It is self explanatory that it contains the content of the message that triggered this `on_message()` event, and you can find the doc [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=message#discord.Message).

Considering that your input message is `solve 5*5`, you could use the method `split()` to get a list of the argument of the message.

```
msg = message.content.split()
# Here msg[0] is "solve"
expression = msg[1]
# Here expression = 5*5
```