# How to replace different strings with different values pretty in a column of dataframe by pandas?

Tags: pandas

### Raw dataframe:

```
A                 B
hello world       a
say hello         a
I try to do it    a
We say            a
like saying hello a
```

### Expectation

For column A, 'world' is replaced by 'a','do' is replaced by 'finish','say' is replaced by 'guess'.

### Trying

```
df['A'].str.replace('world','a').str.replace('do','finish').str.replace('say','guess')
```

It's done but it's a long code and very inefficient, especially dealing with many strings( >100 ).

### Hope

A more pretty and concise way to replace multiple strings in pandas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
rep_dict = dict([
        ('world', 'a'), ('do', 'finish'), ('say', 'guess')
    ])

df.replace(rep_dict, regex=True)

                     A  B
0              hello a  a
1          guess hello  a
2   I try to finish it  a
3             We guess  a
4  like guessing hello  a
```

Comment: great，but what if I have 100 strings to replace.

Comment: Then you create a dictionary with 100 words and their replacement values.  Is there something that I'm missing?

Comment: Sorry. My point is how to create 100 pair strings efficiently into a dict but I know how to do it after thinking a while. For example, write those strings into a file and read it into a dictionary.

Comment: How are your pair strings stored?  Does my latest edit help?

Comment: How about this method?
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4803999/python-file-to-dictionary

Comment: So your saying that your string pairs are in a file?  Each line of the file constitutes a pair separated by a space?  You need to update your question with this information.  This fundamentally changes the question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143487/discussion-between-jack-and-pirsquared).

Comment: Not exactly. The method you supply is using dict and dataframe.str.replace(dict, regex=True). But there are many ways to build dict. The orginal question including the situation when there are multiple strings. I think your answer works well for less than 10 strings but not work well for more than 10. But I have update question to let others know what I want to do.

Comment: In order to perform this task, you need to supply the strings in some form.  A file?  Database?  Another dataframe?  It has to come from somewhere.  You haven't stated where from.  I can't magically tell you how to create a pretty replace methodology if you won't tell me where these strings are.  As it is, I've answered your exact question and you are adding details after the fact.  It is much better to include all details that you need addressed in the original question so we(I) don't end up wasting time.