# How to read a file as a list / dict?

Tags: python, list, file, dictionary

I have a file which has the same structure as python list / dictionaries, i.e.

```
[
    {
      "key1" : "value1",
      "key2" : "value2",
       ...
    },
    {
      "key1" : "value3",
      "key2" : "value4",
      ...
    },
    ...
]
```

Is there some easy way how to read this file and convert it into a list of dictionaries?

Comment: It looks like this is `json`... You can use the [`json`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) library.

Comment: Or, in more general case, look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4803999/python-file-to-dictionary).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
with open('your_file', encoding='utf-8') as data_file:
   data = json.loads(data_file.read())
```

Answer (score 2):

if the file is a json file, then

```
import json
with open('file_url') as data_file:    
    data = json.load(data_file)
    print(data[0]['key1'])        
    print(data[0]['key2'])
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to look into the [JSON](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/json.html) module. If that is the format of your file, of course. If not, you can write your own text parser. It'd be helpful to have more information about your use case, where the file comes from, and that kind of stuff.