# Convert a file into dictionary

Tags: python, file, dictionary

I have a file comprising three columns, i.e.

`a 1 4
b 2 5
c 3 6`

I wish to read this file to a dictionary so that column 1 is the key and 
column 2 and 3 is the value, i.e.,

`dict = {'a': (1,4), 'b': (2,5), 'c': (3,6)}`

Does anyone have a command for this?

Comment: In what language?  What have you tried?

Comment: What is your definition of 'command'?

Comment: The language is python.

Comment: Added the tag to your question. Nevertheless, what have you tried so far?

Comment: For example, I have tried this link `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4803999/how-to-convert-a-file-into-a-dictionary`, but none of them work for me. Moreover, I have three columns, not two.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is the same as the one in the link you mentioned in the comments. Except you unpack three values in a line instead of two.

*test.txt* (your text file)

```
a 1 4
b 2 5
c 3 6
```

*Your code:*

```
d = {}
with open("test.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
       (key, val1, val2) = line.split()
       d[key] = (int(val1), int(val2))
```

---

```
print(d)
```

gives you,

```
{'a': (1, 4), 'b': (2, 5), 'c': (3, 6)}
```