# How to read txt file into a Dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

How can I read a text file containing

example:

```
qtsdatacenter.aws.edu 128.60.3.2 A

www.ibm.com 64.42.3.4 A

www.google.edu 8.7.45.2 A
```

Into a Dictionary like this:

```
 tsdictionary = {   "qtsdatacenter.aws.com" : "qtsdatacenter.aws.edu 128.60.3.2 A",     
                     "www.ibm.com" : "www.ibm.com 64.42.3.4 A",
                     "www.google.edu" : "www.google.edu 8.7.45.2 A"
                }
```

Where the first string read before a space also becomes the key.

Comment: Do you know how to read lines from a file?

Comment: fp = open('myfile.txt', 'r') ?

Comment: can you share your solution where you showed effort to solve the problem, please?

Comment: The answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4803999/how-to-convert-a-file-into-a-dictionary

Comment: sure, here     rsdictionary = {}

    with open("PROJI-DNSRS.txt") as f:
        for line in f:
            (key, val) = line.split()
            rsdictionary[int(key)] = val

Comment: This method is giving me this error ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Comment: always put code in question, not in comment.

Comment: @user586327 this is because you have 3 elements and trying to unpack to 2 variables. You can do `key, *val = line.split()` to unpack all other elements into `val`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve something like this with the following:

```py
my_dict = dict()

with open("data.txt") as data:
  for line in data:
    site , *_= line.strip().split(" ", 1)
    if site:
      my_dict[site] = line.strip()

print(my_dict)
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. It works perfectly fine !

Comment: @user586327 If this satisfies your question, would you accept my answer as the solution? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
rsdictionary = {}
with open("PROJI-DNSRS.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        (key, val) = line.strip().split(" ", 1)
        rsdictionary[key] = "{} {}".format(key, val)
```