# Trying to get key-value pairs from a string

Tags: python, string, dictionary

I want to make a method that reads a file and returns a dictionary with the given key-value pairs in the file, but I am new to python and don't know how to do it. The string input is values followed by keys, and then a newline, like this:

```
6 ove
6 ver
5 rov
```

The keys should be the string and the values the integers. I already tried this:

```
with open(filename, "r", encoding="utf-8") as conn:
    text = conn.read().splitlines()
    for line in text:
        for value, key in line:
            result[key] = int(value)
```

But I think it reads the whole line as the value. Hope someone can help

Comment: try `for value, key in line.split(" "):`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert a file into a dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4803999/how-to-convert-a-file-into-a-dictionary) with the small change of switching between `key` and `val`

Comment: As a side note, it is not necessary to read the whole file as a single string. remove the `text = ...` line and just do `for line in conn:`

Comment: Thank you Tomerikoo! That indeed answers my question! I don't know how to reference your answer as the best, but that did the trick!

Answer (score 1):

The line is a `str`, does not have a value and key.

To turn it into a `list`, you can do `line.split()` the string into words. It will split on any whitespace:

```
for value, key in line.strip().split():
    ...
```

The strip() removes heading and trailing  spaces and linefeeds.