# How to turn a text file into a python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, text-files

If I had a text file with the following texts:

```
string, float

string 2, float 2

string 3, float 3

... and so on
```

How would I turn this into a python dictionary?

**Ultimately, I would like all of my strings to become the key and all of the floats to become the value.**

I have tried turning this into a set, yet I was unable to get to where I wanted it to be.

I have also tried the following code, as I saw another post with a similar problem giving me this solution. Yet, I was unable to get it to print anything.

```
m={}   
for line in file:
    x = line.replace(",","")     # remove comma if present
    y=x.split(':')               #split key and value
    m[y[0]] = y[1]
```

Thank you so much.

Comment: "_unable to print anything_" can u also post the output?vs the expected output

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert a file into a dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4803999/how-to-convert-a-file-into-a-dictionary)

Answer (score 0):

If every line in the text file is formatted exactly as it is in the example, then this is what I would do:

```
m = {}
for line in file:
  comma = line.find(", ") # returns the index of where the comma is
  s = line[:comma] 
  f = line[comma+1:]

  m[s] = str.strip(f) # str.strip() removes the extra spaces
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to research more. Don't be lazy.

```
m = {}

for line in file:
    (key, value) = line.split(',') # split into two parts
    m[key] = value.strip('\n')     # remove the line break and append to dictionary


# output
# {'string1': ' 10', 'string2': ' 11'}
```