# Python mutliline regex - Multiple Tags and Conditions

Tags: python, regex, multiline

I got to admit, that my Regex qualities are rather poor, and I (as in this case) avoid them by other solutions. However, in this case for stability and cleanness I would really much like to have a solution.
The input file looks es follows:

```
MAIN: name
  attr1: str
  attr2: str
  attr3: str

SUB: name
  attr1: str
  attr2: str
  attr3: str

MAIN: name
  attr1: str
  attr2: str

SUB: name
  attr1: str
  attr2: str

SUB: name
  attr1: str

SUB: name
  attr1: str
  attr2: str
  attr3: str
```

An entry always starts with an unindented `MAIN` followed by a `collon` and a `name`.

Following are `1 to N`  indented key-value pairs.

Then there are `0 to N` unindented entries with `SUB:name`, again followed by indented attributes.

There is an empty line between each entry (regardless of `MAIN` or `SUB`.

The `Output` should be as following

```
output = {main_name:
             {
               'attr1': str,
               'attr2': str,
               ...
               'subs': [
                          {
                              'name': sub_name,
                              'attr1': str,
                              ...
                          },
                          {...}
                       ]
             }

          main_name2: 
             {
              ...
             }
          }
```

My current approach is something like:

```
entries = input.split('\n\n')
entries = [entry.replace(" ","").split("\n") for entry in entries]
entries = [attribute.split(":") for entry in entries for attribute in entry]
```

and then iterate over the items with lots of ifs and elses to generate the key-value structure described.

Can someone hint me to an elegant way to deal with such a structure, that is in fact very well defined and should be handleable :)

Cheers and thanks guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate line by line, building the structure while you go. You just need to keep track of your current place in order to put the attributes where they belong:

```
def parse_data(data):
    out = {}
    for line in data.splitlines():
        if not line:
            continue
        if line.startswith("MAIN"):
            name = line[6:]
            out[name] = {}
            current = out[name]
        elif line.startswith("SUB"):
            subname = line[5:]
            out[name].setdefault('subs', []).append({'name': subname})
            current = out[name]['subs'][-1]
        elif line.startswith('  '):
            attr, value = line[2:].split(':')
            value = value.strip()
            current[attr] = value
            
    return out


data = """
MAIN: main1
  attr1: str
  attr2: str
  attr3: str
​
SUB: 1.1
  attr1: str
  attr2: str
  attr3: str
​
MAIN: main2
  attr1: str
  attr2: str
​
SUB: 2.1
  attr1: str
  attr2: str
​
SUB: 2.2
  attr1: str
​
SUB: 2.3
  attr1: str
  attr2: str
  attr3: str
"""
```

Output:

```
​
print(parse_data(data))


{'main1': {'attr1': 'str',
  'attr2': 'str',
  'attr3': 'str',
  'subs': [{'name': '1.1', 'attr1': 'str', 'attr2': 'str', 'attr3': 'str'}]},
 'main2': {'attr1': 'str',
  'attr2': 'str',
  'subs': [{'name': '2.1', 'attr1': 'str', 'attr2': 'str'},
   {'name': '2.2', 'attr1': 'str'},
   {'name': '2.3', 'attr1': 'str', 'attr2': 'str', 'attr3': 'str'}]}}
```

Answer (score 0):

For such a structure, I wouldn't use a regex directly for reading the file, to be honest. The structure of the data looks like a nested [dictionary](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp).

How about creating a dictionary object and populate the keys, the sub-dictionary and the sub-keys while reading the file?

You can see a couple of examples of populating a python dictionary from a text file [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4803999/how-to-convert-a-file-into-a-dictionary).